# Centering a UIView within a UIScrollView Xamarin.iOS

Tags: uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I am currently trying to center a UIIView inside of a UIScrollView and am having some difficulty in doing so.

Here is the image of my current view:

[image: UIViewController]

Here is the code snippet I'm working with:

```
public void AddView(UIViewController viewCont)
        {
            this.AddChildViewController(viewCont);
            this.mainScrollView.AddSubview(viewCont.View);
            viewCont.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            var m = new Menu();
            //var c = new Camera();

            AddView(m);
            AddView(c);


            CGRect cFrame = c.View.Frame;
            cFrame.X = this.View.Frame.Width;
            c.View.Frame = cFrame;

            this.mainScrollView.ContentSize = new CGSize(this.View.Frame.Width * 2, 1.0);
        }
```

I want to fill this whole view with Green but as you can see, the bottom quarter of the View does not stretch all the way to the bottom.

For the time being, I have removed all constraints because every attempt in adding them results in no successes. I was hoping to get a concrete answer here as to how I could go about centering this view within this UIScrollView.

Thanks

**UPDATE: 3-21-2017**

My main goal is to have 2 ViewControllers side by side within my UIScrollView that I can navigate to and from using a swipe gesture, like SnapChat. Following, @Digitalsa1nt suggestions, I unfortunately come up with the same issue.

Here are some more pictures:

This first one shows what happens when I only add the 1 view:

[image: UIViewControllerTwo]

This next one shows what happens when I try to add both views to my UIScrollView, only the camera shows:

[image: CameraView]

Finally, here is the code that I am using to back my Camera view:

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using AVFoundation;

namespace BRB.iOS
{
    public partial class Camera : UIViewController
    {
        AVCaptureSession captureSession;
        AVCaptureStillImageOutput stillImageOutput;
        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer previewLayer;

        public Camera() : base("Camera", null)
        {

        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use
        }

        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

            previewLayer.Frame = cameraView.Bounds;
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            captureSession = new AVCaptureSession();
            captureSession.SessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset1920x1080;

            var backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.GetDefaultDevice(AVMediaType.Video);

            NSError error;
            var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput.FromDevice(backCamera, out error);

            if (error == null && captureSession.CanAddInput(input))
            {
                captureSession.AddInput(input);
                stillImageOutput = new AVCaptureStillImageOutput();
                stillImageOutput.OutputSettings = new NSDictionary(AVVideo.CodecKey, AVVideo.CodecJPEG);

                if (captureSession.CanAddOutput(stillImageOutput))
                {
                    captureSession.AddOutput(stillImageOutput);

                    previewLayer = new AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(captureSession);
                    previewLayer.VideoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.ResizeAspect;
                    previewLayer.Connection.VideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait;
                    cameraView.Layer.AddSublayer(previewLayer);
                    captureSession.StartRunning();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually override 'didlayoutsubviews' for making changes to the views within my UIScrollViews. The below worked for me.

```
    public void AddView(UIViewController viewCont)
    {
        AddChildViewController(viewCont);
        mainScrollView.AddSubview(viewCont.View);
        viewCont.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);
    }

    public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();
        // Ensure our contentinsets are 0 so we don't have any blank space
        mainScrollView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        // set the contentsize to the bounds of the container view within.
        mainScrollView.ContentSize = View.Bounds.Size;
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        var m = new Menu();
        //var c = new Camera();

        AddView(m);
        AddView(c);
    }
```

Comment: I have gone ahead and updated my initial question reflecting some of the changes that you proposed, any ideas on what else I can do?

Comment: Is there any reason why you couldn't use a swipe gesture and transition between two UIViewControllers? that way you wouldn't need to fit both into one UIScrollView, they could each have their own?

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and try that, though I may have figured out a way to accomplish this through code. Thanks!

Comment: Any time, let us know if you run into any related issues. good luck.